# Ubuntu stuck at "Record successful boot for GRUB" on boot

Tags: boot, 19.04

I've installed Ubuntu 19.04 on an old laptop which is very slow with Windows 10. After installing Ubuntu, it asked me to restart the laptop. But when I restart, it hangs up infinitely on this screen:

[image]

So, how can I successfully boot Ubuntu on this laptop?

Comment: What laptop & what are its specs particularly RAM & graphics card/chip? If very old, it may be better with Lubuntu as a lighter weight gui.

Comment: Specs are more than enough to run it -nvidia 710m GPU and 6gb ram

Comment: With nVidia are you using nomodeset boot parameter? UEFI or BIOS install? https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-itShows both BIOS (black) screen with f6, and UEFI/grub boot screen where you directly edit grub. If UEFI and after install whether UEFI or BIOS you have to edit grub until you install the nVidia driver into your install. If you check install proprietary drivers, it should install a correct nVidia driver.

Comment: I think I worked out the problem based on you comment oldfred - so thank you. I actually had already checked the box for proprietary drivers. I reinstalled ubuntu and left the box unchecked and it seems to have done the trick. I think it was the nvidia drivers interfering.